# Unity development build not connecting to profiler

Tags: unity, profiler

my development build( with auto connect profiler checked ) is not working. The build runs correctly but no data is displayed in the profiler window. In the console, it says failed to connect.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a bit more information on what steps you did and if you could provide few screenshots of how your profiler is responding. Also which unity version you are using?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110201/discussion-on-question-by-devgam-e-unity-development-build-not-connecting-to-pro). Please consider editing your question to include the troubleshooting details so a user does not need to read the whole chat thread to understand your problem.

Comment: Allow your game to receive connections in Windows Firewall. Your App will communicate and send data through your Wifi. So if you will not allow that and keep it marked private your profiler is most probably not working because of it. If you could just turn it on and see if it's working alright then it's worth checking out? Also I would suggest you to keep your comments in one big comment as extended comments are not recommended.

https://computing.which.co.uk/hc/en-gb/articles/209752885-Allow-or-block-programs-with-the-Windows-Firewall

Comment: Still not working